# How to send on-demand data to client from the server

Tags: python, server, python-asyncio, httpserver, tcpserver

I have implemented a TCP server using asyncio that receives data from the client at regular intervals, let's say every 30 seconds. Now, I aim to send data to the client on-demand. To achieve this, I intend to establish a mechanism where I can set specific parameters on the client side. Consequently, I need to transmit messages from the server to the client for this purpose.

I have tried to implement this but it is not working

this is my code

```
import asyncio
from protocol import Message  # Import your Message class from protocol.py

class TCPServer:

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.server = None
        self.clients = {}  # Dictionary to store connected clients
        self.input_queue = asyncio.Queue()  # Queue for console input

    async def handle_client(self, reader, writer):
       message = Message()  # Create an instance of your Message class
       addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

       # Convert the client address to a string for consistency
       client_address = f"{addr[0]}:{addr[1]}"

       try:
           self.clients[client_address] = writer  # Store the writer for this client

           while True:
               data = await reader.read(1024)
               if not data:
                   break

               # Assuming your Message class has a `raw_data` method
               response = message.raw_data(data)

               print(f"Received {data!r} from {addr!r}")

               print(f"Send: {response!r}")
               writer.write(response.encode())
               await writer.drain()

    except ConnectionResetError as e:
        print(f"ConnectionResetError: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"Client {addr!r} closed the connection")
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()
        del self.clients[client_address]  # Remove the client from the list when they 
       disconnect

    async def send_to_client(self, client_address, message):
          if client_address in self.clients:
             writer = self.clients[client_address]
             writer.write(message.encode())
             await writer.drain()
         else:
             print("Client not found or not connected.")

   async def start(self):
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server(
        self.handle_client, self.host, self.port)

        addr = self.server.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print(f'Serving on {addr}')

        async with self.server:
            await self.server.serve_forever()

  async def stop(self):
        if self.server:
           self.server.close()
           await self.server.wait_closed()
           print("Server stopped")

  async def console_input(self):
       while True:
           client_address = await self.input_queue.get()
           hex_data = input("Enter the hex data to send: ")
           try:
               byte_data = bytes.fromhex(hex_data)
               await self.send_to_client(client_address, byte_data)
          except ValueError:
               print("Invalid hex data format.")

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     host = '127.0.0.1'  # Change this to the desired host
     port = 8888  # Change this to the desired port

     server = TCPServer(host, port)

    async def main():
        try:
          server_task = asyncio.create_task(server.start())
          console_task = asyncio.create_task(server.console_input())

          # Add client address to the input queue for testing
          await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Wait for the server to start (adjust as needed)
          client_address = '127.0.0.1:8888'
          server.input_queue.put_nowait(client_address)

          await asyncio.gather(server_task, console_task)
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print("KeyboardInterrupt: Server shutting down...")
          await server.stop()

  asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976658/5640517

Comment: You'll need to either maintain a permanent connection, poll the server for the data, or reverse the roles. That last one is likely to run into issues with regards to NAT and firewalls.